# Using HashTable without overriding hashcode()

Tags: java, hashing, collections

Today I was asked this question during an interview:

> What will happen if we do not override the `hashcode` method for our
>   class, then add it to `HashTable` and then try to get objects?

What could go wrong?

Comment: Read [this book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) if you want to get a job programming java.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I have a job already)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The idea with a `HashTable` when you try retrieving an object is that the data structure computes the hash code of the object using the `GetHashCode()` method and then goes through a list using the `Equals()` method.

With default `GetHashCode()` implementation, two perfectly similar objects might end up yielding different hash codes which means that if you do not use the exact same instance, you will never find the your object in the `HashTable`.

In general, you want to make sure of two things when implementing hash codes:

- If `A.Equals(B)` then `A.GetHashCode()==B.GetHashCode()`
- Try to get a distribution of hash codes properly spread to get the maximum efficiency from the hash table (if too few hash codes are possible, you'll end up searching a list).

Comment: The method is hashCode(), not GetHashCode().

Comment: I believe @SRKX was using C# in his example, where hashCode is the Java equivalent. The answer is valid in both languages.

Comment: @SpencerK: yeah as DevSolo said, I was trying to explain the concept not to get into language-specific details which is, I hope, what the interviewer is looking for.

Answer (score 6):

> What's gonna happen if we do not override hashcode method for our class, then add it to HashTable and then try to get objects?

It depends on what "adding to HashTable" means. Java's [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) doesn't have any `add` method. The interviewer probably meant `put` method, which takes in a *key* and a *value*. The value can be anything (could be even `null` in HashMap, which is the present-day version of Hashtable). Nothing special happens regardless of whether or not you override the value object's hashcode, or any other method.

The interviewer probably meant that the key object's hashcode wouldn't be overridden. Only then the object identity issues, as pointed out in other answers, come into play. Even then, you don't necessarily have to override the key's hashcode. For example, if you use `String`s as keys, they already have an appropriate hashcode implementation in them. Besides, they can't be subclassed. Furthermore, if you *do* override hashcode but *don't* override equals, you may get some amazing behavior...

If the question really was exactly what you wrote, I would have teased the interviewer with these questions. A good programmer doesn't *assume* that the interviewer probably meant this or that. He asks instead.

Comment: Hashtable does not support null.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "nothing bad unless you have overridden `equals()`".

The general point is that if two objects compare equal i.e. if

```
 a.equals(b)
```

then they must have the same hashcode i.e.

```
 a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()
```

also if two objects have different hash codes, they must not compare equal.

This is especially relevant when you put objects in a hash table.  This is because a hash table is an array of lists (called buckets usually).  The hash bucket is indexed using the hash code, typically you use `hashCode % arraySize`.

So when you put an object in the hash table, you take the hash code of the key and use it to determine the bucket.  You then put a key-value pair in the bucket.  When you want to retrieve an object from the hash table, you take the hash code of the key to find the bucket and test the key of all the key-value pairs in the bucket with `.equals()` to determine which object is the one you want.

So if you have two key objects which compare equal but have different hash codes and you use one as a key in a hash table, you won't be able to search for it using the other key object because you'll be looking in the wrong bucket.

The implementation of `equals()` in Object only returns true if the two objects are actually the same object and `hashCode()` returns the object reference.  However, if you override `equals()` (e.g. String does so that different strings containing the same character sequence compare equal) then you must override `hashCode()`

Comment: Good answer, but I think the first sentence is misleading. If you are using a HashMap or Hashtable, you should override `hashCode()` and `equals()`. The first sentence is only true if you really intend to use object identity as equality e.g. you really want to compare objects with `==` instead of `equals()`.

Comment: @scarfridge: I kind of agree that just using object identity to identify the keys is pretty much useless.  I was thinking nothing bad in terms of (for example) having the value of hashCode() change while the object is being used as a key in a map.

Answer (score 4):

you won't find your object if you get with a different object that is `equal` to the object you put

or to give an example:

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass(1);
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass(1);
assert obj1.equals(obj2);
assert obj1.hashcode()!=obj2.hashcode(); //this is wat happens if you don't inclde hashcode
table.put(obj1,2);
table.get(obj2) // will likely return null but that is a gamble
table.get(obj1) // but this will return the object passed in
```

the reason for this is that HashTable (and HashMap) will use the hashcode to limit the space it has to search through to find the object and that relies on the assumption that if `obj1.equals(obj2)` then `obj1.hashcode == obj2.hashcode()`

Answer (score 3):

I would only add, that all of these concepts have to with *identity* and *comparison*.

There is a contract with hash code:

1.) Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

2.) If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

3.) It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

The upshot is that if the hash codes are the same the entries in the table overwrite each other and that could be surprising to some...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: similar objects (all fields having equal values) would not create the same hash code, so you would need exactly the same (identical) object that was used for `put` to retrieve from hashtable, which is not feasible in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your class extends only `Object`, then the `hashCode()` implementation of your class will depend on the *object identity*. I.e. that the hash code of two different instances will (almost certainly) be different, even if they hold the exact same value.

This means that you will most likely not find the object again in the Map (you *might* find it by chance, however).

Answer (score 1):

If the hashcode method is not overridden, the answer to this question really depends on if the  same key object which was used to `"put"` is going to used for `"get"` as well:

a) If the same key object is used -  `"get"` will find the value. Because it will locate the bucket using the same `"key"` and hence will find the value object.

b) If some another "equivelent" key object is used - Since possibly the hashcode is going to be different due to default implementation of the hashcode method in  `Object` and hence it might get into a different bucket and might not be able to get the value object.